# Extracting Custom Attributes from Okra OIDC's `.well-known/openid-configuration` claims_supported using NextAuth

Tags: claims, next-auth

I'm using Okra OIDC and trying to add custom attributes. I've confirmed that the key I added exists in claims_supported via .well-known/openid-configuration. How can I extract this value using NextAuth?

Thanks for reading